# Detect the content has been inserted into UIcollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: containerView.frame ,collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView?.contentSize.width
```

I found that it cannot find the content size immediately after init the collection view.

How can i detect the content has been inserted into uicollectionview?

Or alternatively, how can i insert the content immediately?

Comment: when you perform reload data then content size will be available

Comment: i tried reloadData() before getting content size, but i still fail

Comment: Can you specify what do you really need? Is it the content size? Or when the content is inserted?

Comment: how can i detect the content has been already inserted

Comment: If you call `layoutIfNeeded()` after you call `reloadData()`, the `contentSize` should be correct. The collection view doesn't actually update until the next render pass so calling layoutIfNeeded forces the layout to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use performBatchUpdates ([Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates)) to get notified when the data is loaded and showed

```
func performBatchUpdates(_ updates: (() -> Void)?, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

> Animates multiple insert, delete, reload, and move operations as a group

---

**So your actual code will look something like this:**

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: containerView.frame ,collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: { (successFinish) in
     self.collectionView?.contentSize.width
})
```